# Об отсутствии запятой в "Объясните(,) почему"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, наречия, местоимение

1. > Объясните почему. Расскажите как.

Но:

> Объясните **,** почему так. Расскажите **,** как именно.
>
> Объясните *то* **,** почему. Расскажите *о том* **,** как.

Объясните то, почему в сложноподчинённом предложении запятой не может быть, если:

— придаточная часть состоит из одного слова,

— в главной части нет указательного местоимения/местоименного наречия, указывающего на союзное слово*.

Желательно, чтобы объяснение было логичным, а то я не зря привёл обратные примеры для сравнения.

1.1. * — подобного рода предложения, но с союзом, а не с союзным словом, невозможны.

2. Но, если Вы так же не согласны с отсутствием запятой, можете где-либо высказаться.

Answer (score 1):

Пунктуация - система условностей. Есть правило не признавать полноценным предложением придаточное, редуцированное до одного только союзного слова, - запятая не ставится.

> §107. Запятая между главным и придаточным предложениями
>
> Примечание 2. Не ставится запятая между
>   главным и следующим за ним придаточным предложением:
>
> в) если придаточное предложение состоит из
>   одного только союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия),
>   например: *Меня упрекают, но не знаю в чем; Уходя, он обещал скоро
>   вернуться, но не уточнил когда; Мать температуру определяла губами:
>   приложит губы ко лбу и сразу определит сколько.*
>
> (Розенталь и др., СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ
>   РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, 1999)
>
> http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm

В последних двух примерах некорректно употреблено указательное местоимение "то": оно указывает на одинокое союзное слово, а не на законченную ситуацию.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Читайте Розенталя,** он уже ответил на ваш вопрос: "**В условиях контекста** возможна постановка запятой и перед одиночным союзным словом, например: **Что же надо делать? НаучИте, чтО.** Усиленное логическое выделение местоимения.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

2) Обратите внимание на фразу ***в условиях контекста***. Это значит, что логическое выделение слов напрямую связано с содержанием предыдущего текста.

3) **И еще важная деталь:** именно запятая и связанная с ней пауза влияет на  расстановку логических ударений.

4) **А вот пример с контекстом:**

Вы знаете, **почему** его нет? **ОбъяснИте, почемУ.** (Повтор местоимения ***почему***).

Вы не хотите идти на собрание? **Объясните почему.**

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт ***не может быть*** Вам ответили: может при определённых условиях.

А вот **почему**? - логика такова: союзное слово - средство связи простых предложений в сложноподчинённом, а самого предложения-то и нет, нет новой информации, та, что заключена в союзном слове, уже содержится в предыдущем главном, следовательно, это одно предложение, где союзное слово является членом предложения главного:

*Объясните почему*.Объясните  что? Почему - дополнение.

*Расскажите как.* Расскажите о чём?  О чём - дополнение

Если же в главной части **есть указательное местоимение/местоименное наречие, указывающее на союзное слово**, это означает, что есть и придаточное предложение, ведь на его присутствие указывает указательное слово. Тогда запятая ставится:

*Объясните то , почему. Расскажите о том , как.*

*Объясните , почему так. * Почему так - неполное предложение. На присутствие сказуемого указывает обстоятельство ТАК. Обстоятельство всегда относится к сказуемому. Легко восстанавливается и нулевое подлежащее: *Объясните , почему это так происходит*.

Расскажите , как именно. Частица ИМЕННО указывает на какую-то информацию, эту информацию можно восстановить из предыдущего текста, это контекстуально неполное предложение, часто используется в диалогах. Поэтому здесь тоже запятая.